# Need Standalone app to test REST API as Browser plugin installation is restricted

Tags: rest, resteasy, web-api-testing

Browser plugins like REST client or Postman is blocked in my organisation.Is there a standalone application which is an alternative for testing REST API?

Comment: [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/)?

Comment: Using Jmeter solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use this console for REST API testing:

https://apigee.com/console/others?apig_cc=1

Comment: I am not getting the right "response" on using this

Comment: What do you mean right "response". If you are getting incorrect response, then possibly check the REST API.

Comment: If this answer solves your problem, please accept the answer and upvote it,

Comment: No this doesn't solve my problem. I am not getting correct response with this. There is nothing wrong with the REST API i checked, as it gave the correct response when tested in the browser.